# How to edit the interface connection in xcode 6?

Tags: ios, xcode, interface

I just started to learn ios programming this week.... When I connection the button from storyboard to the swift code I forgot to change the connection to Action. So can anyone tell to how to edit it? Plus, if I don't want to use any of the connections how can I delete it? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Select your UI element in interface builder, open the Utilities panel and the Connections inspector should show all of your `IBOutlets` and `IBActions`.

[image: Connections inspector]

Here you can remove a connection by pressing the "X" icon.

Answer (score 0):

When you right click on your UIButton as follows,

[image: uibutton state]

you can see **Send Events**, under which there is Touch Up inside which shows the action **clickMe** it is connected to. You can delete it by pressing delete, **x** sign, next to it.
And then to bind the button with other action, select and drag from Touch Up Inside and release on your selected action method implementation on your view controller implementation.

Answer (score 0):

To modify any Storyboard Connections:

- Select your storyboard
- Select the view you want to modify
- Open the Utilities column (right most button in the top right corner of XCode).
- In Utilities column, select Connections Inspector (right most button; looks like an arrow)
- Click on the "X" for connections you want to remove.

If you want to trigger a callback when the button is selected:

- Create a method in your view controller (i.e. -(IBAction)buttonCallback:(id)sender{...} )
- Go to your Storyboard
- Hold Ctrl and click on the UIButton, now drag the cursor to your view controller and release.
- The method buttonCallback should show up, just click it.